# What happens to the baby?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-bronx-tale

In A Bronx Tale, When C is dropped off outside his apartment from his dads bus, at the beginning of the movie, there is a baby crying upstairs and he decides to skip out instead of going home.

Later, both his parents are on the little balcony and mom says she's going to go check on the baby.

Whatever happened to the baby?